# Retrieve the value of closest select option to a button

Tags: jquery, html

When the user clicks the 'Confirm' button I want to get the `<option value>` of the select element above the button.

I'm using jquery 3.2.1 and thought I could target this with `.closest`, but this logs `undefined`.

If I change the selector from `.confirm-btn` to `.action-options` it will log `/clone/update/12/MERGE` for all buttons pressed. So it's not reading anything except the first set of select values.

I've based this on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141801/get-closest-selected-option) but can't see what else I can target.

Please can someone help?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.confirm-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var x = $('.confirm-btn').closest('select').find(':selected').val();
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/12/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/12/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/12/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>

<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/11/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/11/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/11/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>

<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/10/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/10/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/10/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main issues here. Firstly `closest()` is used to find a *parent* element. The `select` is a *sibling* of the `button`, so you need to use `prev()` instead in this case.

Secondly, you need to select the `button` which raised the event in order to traverse the DOM from that specific element. To do that use the `this` keyword in the selector. Your current logic is selecting *all* the `.confirm-btn` elements, which will result in only the first instance being used in the `prev()` call.

Also note that `find(':selected')` is redundant; you can just call `val()` on the `select` directly.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.confirm-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var x = $(this).prev('select').val();
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/12/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/12/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/12/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>

<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/11/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/11/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/11/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>

<select class="form-control action-options">
  <option value="/clone/update/10/MERGE">Merge</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/10/REPLACE">Replace</option>
  <option value="/clone/update/10/REJECT">Reject</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: I can see it works in your fiddle but it's giving me `undefined` still. The markup in this case is being loaded into the page as an ajax response. That's why I was using `$('body').on('click', '.confirm-btn' ... `. Would that change anything in terms of the answer?

Comment: No, that's the correct way to attach a delegated event handler for dynamic content. Without seeing how you've implemented this code I can't really help, as you can see from the above that it works in isolation. Perhaps if you created a https://jsfiddle.net to demo the issue?

Comment: Got it working. There was an extra `<div>` surrounding the `<button>` in my application. When this was removed the code works as per your fiddle. I don't actually need the `<div>` as it was being used to create a margin between the select and button, but the spacing class can be applied to the button so works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For dynamically created and injected elements, you need to look into the document. Use below code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirm-btn', function() {    
  var x = $(this).prev('select').val();
  //rest of your code goes here..
});
```

Comment: You can use `body` as per the accepted answer. This makes no difference in this case.